# Как мне получить все выбранные мной элементы в другом активити (RecyclerView)?

Tags: java, android

у меня есть метод, где я перебираю свой List

```
public void onClickYes(View view) {
    display.setText(worldList.get(i));
    progress.setText(counter + "");
    wordItems.add(new RecyclerItems(worldList.get(i)));
    builderAdapter();
    if (i < worldList.size()) {
        i++;
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Слова закончились", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

А тут я пытаюсь передавать значение в новом активити

```
            case R.id.yes:
                wordItems.add(new RecyclerItems(worldList.addAll()));
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", worldList.size());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
```

Я хочу заполнить мой recyclerView в другом активити заполнить всеми выбранными элементами,
но у меня так сделать не получается и выводит только один элемент.
Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: А вам не кажется что `worldList.size()` это размер массива а не его содержимое? В целом и в общем, нужно хранить массив с id элементов, передать его через intent и в другом активити принять переданные данные.

Comment: Да, это размер массива. Я перебираю элементы и хочу заполнить свой recyclerview только теми элементами, которые я уже перебрал.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - использовать отдельный класс где вы сможете засетить ваш список. Либо передавать так:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list);
startActivity(intent);
```

и получить так:

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

Вот есть [подобное обсуждение на enSo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747727/pass-arraylist-of-user-defined-objects-to-intent-android/15747819#). Вам нужно учитывать что ваш класс-модель должен реализовывать (implementation) `Parcelable`. Про независимый класс можно почитать [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/singleton.php). [Вот есть туториал](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/14581/passing-custom-object-between-activities) по передаче объекта между активностями, и вот из него пример класса который передается:

```
public class MyObjects implements Parcelable {
    
    private int age;
    private String name;
    
    private ArrayList<String> address;
    
    public MyObjects(String name, int age, ArrayList<String> address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    
    }
    
    public MyObjects(Parcel source) {
        age = source.readInt();
        name = source.readString();
        address = source.createStringArrayList();
    }
    
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(age);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeStringList(address);
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<String> getAddress() {
        if (!(address == null))
            return address;
        else
            return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    
    public static final Creator<MyObjects> CREATOR = new Creator<MyObjects>() {
        @Override
        public MyObjects[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObjects[size];
        }
    
        @Override
        public MyObjects createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MyObjects(source);
        }
    };
}
```

вам нужно сделать что-то приблизительно такое же, но сложить в массив для передачи дальше.

Comment: Не забывайте о накладных расходах при парселизации и передачи больших данных, уделите внимание варианту предоставленном Andrew. С отдельным классом, например ViewModel общий для нескольких activity.